# How do I reduce a 'group'ed Linq query of back to a flat IEnumerable?

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7

I have a queryable collection of objects with two relevent properties, `Retailer` and `Price`. I want to select an object (the one with the lowest price) for each retailer and then present the list of objects grouped by the first letter of retailer's name e.g. all the objects corresponding to the lowest price for retailers beginning with the letter 'A' in the first group, the next group for 'B' etc.

I'm having hard time figuring out once I have grouped my Linq query by retailer, how to make the `Select` query on the objects without reducing the query to a list of `Price` attributes and hence losing the references to the objects e.g.

```
var query = from o in myCollection.Cast<MyObjectType>()
            group o.GetPrice(someParameter) by o.Retailer into oGroup
            select oGroup.Min() // <-- at this point I've 'lost' the objects 
                                //     and just have a list of prices
                                //     I also need to then group the results 
                                //     by o.Retailer.ToString()[0]
```

I am using Windows Phone 7 so Linq may be limited.

Answer (score 1):

So you just need a list of key value pairs with retailer and minimum price?
Can't you just select an anonymous type then like this?

```
var query = from o in myCollection.Cast<MyObjectType>()
            group o.GetPrice(someParameter) by o.Retailer into oGroup
            select new { Retailer = oGroup.Key, Min = oGroup.Min() };
```

Or you can create a custom class or KeyValuePair too.

Comment: I need the object, not just the price and retailer since there are other properties on the object I need to access later...